# Calculating age of individuals over a range of dates using a source table with their age at one point in time

Tags: sql, date, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How can one calculate the age over multiple dates for customers where not all dates are populated?

Thinking of the problem, I am trying to get the minimum age in a temporary table and then use this table to get to a final table where an age exists for each year for each customer_id.

I know how to get to the `min_age_table` with each person's earliest recorded age and date. I am not sure how to use this to generate a table with each customer's age going sequentially backwards and forwards as shown in the figure below.

[image]

I have set up a minimum working example to try to implement this in the big-query SQL UI.

```
-- CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `dataset_id.project_id.example_table` 
WITH original_table
AS
 (SELECT 'a' as customer_id, '2020-11-01' as snapshot_date, 20 as age UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', '2020-12-01', 21 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', '2020-09-01', 25 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', '2020-10-01', 25 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', '2020-01-01', 45)


-- select customer_id,  min_snapshot_date , age for min table
SELECT 
--original_table.customer_id,
MIN(original_table.snapshot_date) AS min_snapshot_date,
--original_table.age
FROM original_table

-- use min table to get an age for 3 years (will need to be able to increase both ways)
```

Comment: I would consider deriving an estimate date of birth using something like `date_sub(cast(min_date as date), INTERVAL age YEAR)` but this may be off by 1 year for some people. May need to play around with it.

Comment: Use the formula from the user isolated: `date_sub(cast(min_date as date), INTERVAL age YEAR) as X` then calculate the minimum value per user and the difference: `date_diff(max(X),min(X),day) as y`. If y is greater than  365 days the user lied with the age. If it is zero only one day is given and thus the user can be one year older. `365-y ` gives you the amount of days the user can be older.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a simple solution that follows your diagram completely and have annotated it to attempt to help you understand what we are doing.

```
-- Create a temp table to hold the date values
CREATE TEMP TABLE dates (
YEAR INT64
);

-- insert dates in the desired range - have chosen 2015-2022 here as an example
INSERT INTO dates
SELECT
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MY_DATE)
FROM
(
-- this selects dates from 2015-2022, change 2015 to desired start date and 7 to the desired number of years
SELECT DATE_ADD('2015-01-01',INTERVAL param YEAR) AS MY_DATE
FROM unnest(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 7, 1)) as param
)
;

-- create data in the original table
WITH original_table
AS
 (SELECT 'a' as customer_id, '2020-11-01' as snapshot_date, 20 as age UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', '2020-12-01', 21 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', '2020-09-01', 25 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', '2020-10-01', 25 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', '2020-01-01', 45),


-- Select customer_id,  min_snapshot_date, age for min table
min_date_age AS (SELECT 
original_table.customer_id,
DATE(MIN(original_table.snapshot_date)) AS min_snapshot_date,
MIN(original_table.age) AS min_age
FROM original_table
GROUP BY
customer_id)

-- select customer id, and derived snapshot year and age
SELECT 
customer_id,
YEAR AS derived_snapshot_year,
min_age - (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM min_snapshot_date) - YEAR) AS derived_age
FROM min_date_age
-- cross join to create duplicate rows (one for each desired date)
CROSS JOIN dates
ORDER BY
min_date_age.customer_id,
derived_snapshot_year
```

Output table:

[image]

This creates the exact behavior as you have described with your diagram - however as pointed out by other users there are some issues with this output as each year there are technically two ages a user can possibly be in a single year (with the rare exception of people born on XXXX/01/01).

**EDIT**:

Edit to response to the comment.

```
-- Create a temp table to hold the date values
CREATE TEMP TABLE dates (
YEAR INT64
);

-- insert dates in the desired range - have chosen 2015-2022 here as an example
INSERT INTO dates
SELECT
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MY_DATE)
FROM
(
-- this selects dates from 2015-2022, change 2015 to desired start date and 7 to the desired number of years
SELECT DATE_ADD('2015-01-01',INTERVAL param YEAR) AS MY_DATE
FROM unnest(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 7, 1)) as param
)
;

-- create data in the original table
WITH original_table
AS
 (SELECT 'a' as customer_id, '2020-11-01' as snapshot_date, 20 as age UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', '2020-12-01', 21 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', '2020-09-01', 25 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', '2020-10-01', 25 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', '2020-01-01', 45),


-- Select customer_id,  min_snapshot_date, age for min table
min_date_age AS (SELECT 
original_table.customer_id,
DATE(MIN(original_table.snapshot_date)) AS min_snapshot_date,
MIN(original_table.age) AS min_age
FROM original_table
GROUP BY
customer_id),

-- select customer id, and derived snapshot year and age
output AS (SELECT 
customer_id,
YEAR AS derived_snapshot_year,
min_age - (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM min_snapshot_date) - YEAR) AS derived_age
FROM min_date_age
-- cross join to create duplicate rows (one for each desired date)
CROSS JOIN dates
ORDER BY
min_date_age.customer_id,
derived_snapshot_year)

SELECT
...
FROM
other_table
LEFT JOIN
output
ON
other_table.field = output.field
```

Comment: Thank you @JeremySavage , this was a great a great answer. What about if you want to create this table as a sub table to left join onto another table. How does this change how you write it?

Comment: @user4933 - no change, you can just pass the CTE to a LEFT JOIN statement. Of course, if you wanted to save the intermediate data you could just save it to an output table.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, I would like to post an approach for mssql users

```
;WITH
original_table AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        ('a', CAST('2020-11-01' AS DATE), 20),
        ('a', CAST('2020-12-01' AS DATE), 21),
        ('b', CAST('2020-09-01' AS DATE), 25),
        ('b', CAST('2020-10-01' AS DATE), 25),
        --('c', CAST('2020-02-01' AS DATE), 46),
        ('c', CAST('2020-01-01' AS DATE), 45)
    ) x (  customer_id, snapshot_date, age )
),
min_table AS (
    SELECT 
        customer_id, 
        MIN(DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(DAY, -age*364.75, snapshot_date)), 0)) snapshot_date
    FROM original_table
    GROUP BY customer_id
),
years_period AS (
    SELECT * FROM 
    (VALUES 
    (2019), (2020), (2021)
    ) x ( snapshot_year )
)
SELECT 
    customer_id, 
    y.snapshot_year, 
    DATEDIFF(YEAR, m.snapshot_date, DATEADD(YEAR, snapshot_year-1900, 0)) age
FROM years_period y, min_table m
```

And related output

```
customer_id snapshot_year   age
a           2019            20
a           2020            21
a           2021            22
b           2019            24
b           2020            25
b           2021            26
c           2019            44
c           2020            45
c           2021            46
```